# translate strings from format_plural

Tags: i18n-l10n

How to translate the output of [format_plural](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/format_plural/7) which returns a new translatable string every time the count increased.

I put the translation with @count but it returns an array like @count[NUMBER]
the NUMBER increased and for every NUMBER we have a string that need translation.

The translation work if I put @count[NUMBER] and didn't work for NUMBER-1 nor NUMBER+1

How to translate all strings with one translation?

The code comes from [download_count](https://drupal.org/project/download_count) module

And here is the piece of code

```
if (isset($file->downloads) && $file->downloads > 0) {
$output .=     format_plural($file->downloads, 'Downloaded 1 time',     'Downloaded @count times');
```

}

Finally I need to translate plural strings form the translation interface drupal provides and fix the raised number of strings

I have .po files and had changed the [plural-forms as that comment](https://drupal.org/node/87199#comment-159596) then import the file but nothing changed so I need help to fix it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! You should show the code you are using, since it's not clear what you are saying; plus, without seeing the code is not possible to say what is wrong with the code.

Comment: It's not my code mean I need to translate the output of the function through drupal translation interface

Comment: As for "which returns a new translatable string every time the count increased," what is the string that you are trying to translate? If you are speaking of translating through the user interface, I am not sure what you mean by " it returns an array like @count[NUMBER] the NUMBER increased and for every NUMBER we have a string that need translation," since the user interface doesn't return an array.

Comment: Can't you just add 2 translations? One for "Downloaded 1 time" and one for "Downloaded @count times"? `format_plural()` calls `t()` internally so that would make most sense I think

Comment: I did but @count only works for the first time download  mean the string is (downloaded 1 time).the second becomes (downloaded 2 time) --third (downloaded 3 time)Thus I have newly added strings needs translation
I see that the plural forms isn't set correctlly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks all

I found the solution as that comment [form-plural in po](https://drupal.org/node/87199#comment-159596)

Edited on of the po files after exporting the last state to keep translation.

Import the file using drush (uploading from the interface always fail)

Installed [drush_lang](https://drupal.org/project/drush_language) module

Apply that patch [langimp relative path](https://drupal.org/files/1863024-langimp-relpath_0.patch) in /home/$_USER/.drush/drush_language

Clear cache for drupal and drush (drush cache-clear drush)

use the commands that module provides and every thing will be fine